# How to call a function in the same file of main from a function in another file

Tags: c++, function, oop, visual-c++

I have a program with multiple headers and cpp files, I want to call a function defined in the same file main is defined (from a function defined in another file). If I'm correct, the file with the main function never has a corresponding header, right? How would I do it?

Comment: " If I'm correct the file with the main function never has a corresponding header, right?" Only if you don't write one.

Comment: *"If I'm correct the file with the main function never has a corresponding header, right?"* How did you get that idea? Because your IDE did not auto-generate one?

Comment: You just need to *declare* the called function. Often that is (conventionally) done in some header file. You need to read a good book on C++ programming.

Comment: You seem to be in need of [a good book on c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you be allowed to have a header for functions inside `main.cpp`? Assuming `main.cpp` defines `main` and `foo`, nothing prevents you from having a header containing the declaration of `foo`.

In fact, some libraries and frameworks make their own `main`. In cases like these, you just link against the library that contains the `main`.

For example, if you look at the last example code of [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html) of Boost's Unit Test Framework, you will see there is no `main`. The `main` is already written for you inside the Boost Unit Test Framework library.

Comment: "You could even call main from within your program" - Not in C++. Also, I think the Standard forbids declaring main. In any case, the OP is not asking about calling main.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, the c++  iso decided to forbid calling main